# How to show detail info timeline in insight Dynamics 365 Marketing?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I need to add more detail information from Custom Channel Activity on the Interaction timeline.
for example, in this insight from the Contact entity.

[image: Custom Channel Insight]

Does anybody know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today we cannot do much in Custom Channel activity. Looks like this feature request is in [Microsoft Product group backlog](https://community.dynamics.com/365/marketing/f/dynamics-365-for-marketing-forum/368989/how-to-show-detail-information-in-customer-insight-interaction-dynamics-365-marketing), please follow that thread for latest updates & any workaround for the same.